# How to add image(or custom shape) to divider?

Tags: html, css

I want to recreate this divider. How to add the leaves to the divider?
Is there a nicer way to do it besides creating the border in photoshop, export as a jpg and linking it to the divider?

I don't care about the inner section.

[image]

Comment: I would argue that making the whole border using photoshop as one image is better because imagine you have +500 leaves made in SVG or any other HTML element. that would affect the performance, and there's no reason you would ever want to do that. not to mention that this will make it more complex to position the leaves nicely on the screen while maintaining the mobile view at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an SVG as well!

Since the leaves are plain color and linear shapes, why not turn them into a vector?

Here is an example:

```
.divider {
  border-image-source: url(leaves.svg);
}
```